# Links In Header Not Working

Tags: css, wordpress, zurb-foundation

I have a site I'm working on where the links in the header aren't working. http://stage.metooplace.com

This site is in Wordpress, but I am having the same issue on local static pages. Links don't work on either the brand logo link or the Foundation 6 off canvas menu. I also noticed that when I am logged into Wordpress that the links in the admin bar don't work either.

In the console I'm getting the following error(s) when I click one of the links:

```
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /
at Function.ga.error (jquery.min.js:2)
at ga.tokenize (jquery.min.js:2)
at ga.select (jquery.min.js:2)
at Function.ga [as find] (jquery.min.js:2)
at r.fn.init.find (jquery.min.js:2)
at r.fn.init (jquery.min.js:2)
at r (jquery.min.js:2)
at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (app.js:8)
at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
at HTMLDocument.q.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
```

I don't see where there is a syntax problem. Any ideas of what is going on? I can't seem to figure it out and need some fresh eyes on it.

Comment: Those errors are in the jQuery library file itself. That wouldn't have any errors, so it's more likely that there's something wrong with your code. When I get errors like those, it's generally because I forgot a `;` or a `)` somewhere. However, I've never had that break a hyperlink, so I don't know what's going on there.

Comment: This does not really address any of your errors but I got the menu working by changing the `href` value for the items. Each of your sections has an id so just use an anchor that points to that section. For example, `<a href="http://stage.metooplace.com/live-on-mission/">Live On Mission</a>` would become `<a href="#liveOnMission">Live On Mission</a>` Also, your background images repeat on large screens. Here's what that looks like on mine. https://image.ibb.co/gYyW9F/Capture.jpg

Comment: The thing that is strange is that there is a link to an anchor in the off canvas menu that works fine, but not anything else

Comment: I was just working on the background, that's why it was broken. Working now. Yes, I was able to get it working with linking to an anchor too.

Comment: It's not just the header. There is a banner ad at the bottom of the page and it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was within a smooth scroll script I was using. It worked when I changed to https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/